# Twilio.js:264 Uncaught TypeError: url.URL is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, twilio, sms

```
Twilio.js:264 Uncaught TypeError: url.URL is not a constructor
```

Why I'm getting this type of error while using twilio sms api for sending a sms in react js

Here's my code

```js
const accountSid = "ACa7e54c4******391cc08f61bd";
const authToken = "0ab3a929*****c4be9466b6878";
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

const send_sms = (type)=>{
    client.messages
      .create({from: '+19547***', body: 'body', to: '+917828***4'})
      .then(message => console.log(message.sid));
}
```

[image]

Comment: That error looks like it is in browser dev tools, are you trying to run the Twilio module in the browser?

Comment: Oh, I see the tag for ReactJS too, so I'm going to assume you are running this in a browser. Answer incoming.

Comment: Oh good to hear from you @philnash but I also tried before using express server as you mentioned in https://www.twilio.com/blog/send-an-sms-react-twilio  but then I got cors  error "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

Comment: That is going to need a bit more explanation. In that blog post the server and client both work through the same host, so there should be no CORS issues. Perhaps you can ask a new question which describes what you did and how you got the CORS error and we can work on that?

Comment: Yeah sure posting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's pretty much well I got my silly mistake and here's my code
> working well I hope It's right way to so, I'm running my react js server on 3000 port and express server on 4000 so yeah it working well ..

```
//index.js for express server 

const express = require('express'); 
const cors = require('cors');
const twilio = require('twilio'); 

//twilio requirements -- Texting API 
const accountSid = 'ACa7********************1bd';
const authToken = '0ab*****************6b6878'; 
const client = new twilio(accountSid, authToken);

const app = express(); 
app.use(cors()); 

app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Server Running')
})

app.post('/api/send-sms', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello to the Twilio Server')
    const {  msg } = req.query;
    client.messages.create({
        body: "Hello mesage from twilio ..",
        to: "+917******784",  
        from: '+19*******13'
    }).then((message) => console.log(message.body));
})
app.listen(4000, () => console.log("Running on Port 4000"))
```

> And here's the function which get triggered on onClick event

```
const send_sms = (type)=>{

    fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/send-sms', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(msg)
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    })

}
```

> I just wana welcome if correction is needed please let me know because it display only one red alert  *Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token H in JSON at position 0*

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAC4f.png)

> let me just know what I'm missing or needed a correction.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [Twilio Node module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twilio) is not to be used in a browser and will fail to work. This is intentional because you should not directly call the Twilio API from a client side application.

In order to call the Twilio API from the client side you need to embed your Account Sid and Auth Token, as I can see you have done in your example. When you do this, you expose your credentials to anyone who uses your application and a malicious user could extract your credentials and abuse your account.

Instead of making requests to the API from the client side, you should proxy them through your own server. The good news is that I have a blog post you can follow that walks you through [how to send an SMS from React with Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/blog/send-an-sms-react-twilio) that explains this in detail.